# Triggering Instance methods by firing the Parent method

Tags: javascript, oop, function, methods, instances

What is the best way to fire a method in many children by calling the parent's method?

For example, lets say I have a parent object Foo which has many instances: BarX, BarY, etc.

```
Foo = function(){
   x = null;
   y = null;
   move = function(){
      x += 1;
      y += 1;
   };
}

BarX = new Foo();
BarX.x = 50;
BarX.y = 50;

BarY = new Foo();
BarY.x = 200;
BarY.y = 200;
```

Is there any easy way to fire off the move function in all instances? Am I limited to looping through the instances and firing off the function like that or can I somehow fire the function in Foo and have it trickle down and fire off all instances who extend Foo?

Comment: Just a vocabulary note: BarX and BarY are not children of Foo, they are instances.

Comment: Thank you for the vocab note. Fixed within original post.

Answer (score 3):

No. But you could be more clever about it. Make a *static* `moveAll` function on `Foo`. Examples make things clearer. [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jruddell/kqTMw/).

```
var Foo = function(x, y){
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.move = function(){
      x += 1;
      y += 1;
      alert(x + ' ' + ' ' + y);
   };
   Foo.instances.push(this); // add the instance to Foo collection on init
};
Foo.instances = [];
Foo.moveAll = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < Foo.instances.length; i++)
        Foo.instances[i].move();
}

var a = new Foo(5, 6);
var b = new Foo(3, 4);

Foo.moveAll();
```